# How to Change Color of Selected Nodes in TreeView Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, treeview

In a asp.net web site I'm using a `TreeView` to display data from a `xml` file

this is the TreeView HTML code

```
<asp:TreeView ID="trvPILDeepSearch" runat="server" ImageSet="Simple" BackColor="#F8F8F8" BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="#F8F8F8" LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="leafnode" Width="600px" >
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Parent" TextField="TEXT" SelectAction="None"  />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Child" TextField="TEXT" SelectAction="None" />
    </DataBindings>
</asp:TreeView>
```

Now I want to change the text color of the Parent nodes, Is it possible to change the colour only in selected nodes

```
  Name1          <-- Change the color of this
    Detail1  
    Detail2
  Name2          <-- Change the color of this
    Detail2
    Detail2
```

Comment: Did you try to edit the NodeStyle-CssClass attribute of the TreeView ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade I was blind :( there is a attribute called ParentNodeStyle-ForeColor, It works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `RootNodeStyle` for the tree view:

```
/* Styles: put this at style section or at your .css file */
.rootNodeLinkStyle a:link
{
    color: Red;
}

.rootNodeLinkStyle a:hover
{
    color: pink;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

In .aspx: add the css class to the `RootNodeStyle` as below:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="trvPILDeepSearch" runat="server" ImageSet="Simple" BackColor="#F8F8F8" BorderWidth="5px" BorderColor="#F8F8F8" LeafNodeStyle-CssClass="leafnode" Width="600px" >
    <DataBindings>
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Parent" TextField="TEXT" SelectAction="None"  />
        <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Child" TextField="TEXT" SelectAction="None" />
    </DataBindings>
    <RootNodeStyle CssClass="rootNodeLinkStyle" />
</asp:TreeView>
```